# Can't open Xpages in database after updating extlib

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I've designed an application using earlier version of extlib from OpenNTF. Now I've updated the extlib, and when I try to open an Xpage in the database I get the following error: 
*Note that this happens when opening an Xpage in Designer. The database is opened in a browser flawlessly.

```
Could not open the editor: An unexpected exception was thrown.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.XFacesEditPartFactory.createEditPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.createChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.CustomRenderingElementEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.CallbackEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.DocumentEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.CustomRenderingElementEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.DocumentEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.CCCustomRenderingElementEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.CallbackEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.DocumentEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editpart.CCCustomRenderingElementEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.ElementEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.XVENodeEditPart.refreshChildren(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.refresh(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractGraphicalEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editpart.DocumentEditPart.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.AbstractEditPart.addChild(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.editparts.SimpleRootEditPart.setContents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.viewer.XMLGraphicalViewerImpl.setContents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.AbstractEditPartViewer.setContents(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editor.AbstractXMLVisualEditor.initializeGraphicalViewer(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editor.XFacesEditor.initializeGraphicalViewer(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editor.AbstractXMLVisualEditor.createGraphicalViewer(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditor.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editor.AbstractXMLVisualEditor.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.xve.editor.XVEMultiPageEditor.createPages(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.xsp.editor.XFacesMultiPageEditor.createPages(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.dialog.DesignElementUtil.openEditorWithImplicitLock(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.dialog.DesignElementUtil.openEditorWithImplicitLock(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.dialog.DesignElementUtil.openDesignElement(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.dialog.DesignElementUtil.openDesignElement(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.navigator.designtimemodelcontroller.DesignTimeModelWebPages.openDesignElement(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.navigator.DesignEditor.openDesignElement(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.navigator.DesignEditor.openSelectedDesignElement(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.domino.navigator.DesignEditor$13.mouseDoubleClick(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.internal.RCPApplication.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.startLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
```

**UPDATE** I've found out that this custom control is causing the error, but I have no idea why!?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" style="height:340px;"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xe:djAccordionContainer id="djAccordionContainer1"
        style="height:345px;width:197px;">
        <xe:djAccordionPane id="djAccordionPane1" title="За нас"
            style="background-color:rgb(249,252,255)">

            <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="selected" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="За заводот" id="link1"
                value="/zazavodot.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>


            <xp:link escape="true" text="Координативно тело за ИС"
                id="link3" value="/koordinativnotelo.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Меѓународни изложби" id="link4"
                value="/megjunarodniizlozbi.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Промоција" id="link5"
                value="/promocija.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Патент на годината" id="link6"
                value="/patentnagod.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Годишна програма" id="link7"
                value="/godisnaprograma.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Годишен извештај" id="link8"
                value="/godisenizvestaj.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
        </xe:djAccordionPane>
        <xe:djAccordionPane id="djAccordionPane2" title="Легислатива"
            style="background-color:rgb(249,252,255)">
            <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="selected" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Национално законодавство"
                id="link9" value="/nacionalnozakon.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Eu Регулативи и Директиви"
                id="link10" value="/EuRegulativi.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Меѓународни Договори"
                id="link11" value="/megjunarodnidogovori.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" id="link12"
                text="Билатерални договори" value="/bilateralnidogovori.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
        </xe:djAccordionPane>
        <xe:djAccordionPane id="djAccordionPane3" title="Издаваштво"
            style="background-color:rgb(249,252,255)">
            <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="selected" value="false"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Гласник" id="link13"
                value="/glasnik.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Публикации" id="link14"
                value="/publikacii.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Архива" id="link15"
                value="/arhiva.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
        </xe:djAccordionPane>
        <xe:djAccordionPane id="djAccordionPane4"
            title="Корисни информации"
            style="background-color:rgb(249,252,255)">
            <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="selected" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Прашања" id="link16"
                value="/prashanja.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Линкови" id="link17" value="http://wipo.int/members/en/" target="_blank">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Статистика" id="link18"
                value="/statistika.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Новости" id="link19"
                value="/Novosti.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
        </xe:djAccordionPane>
        <xe:djAccordionPane id="djAccordionPane5"
            title="Пристап до информации"
            style="background-color:rgb(249,252,255)">
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="Пристап до информации"
                id="link20" value="/pristapdoinfo.xsp">
            </xp:link>
            <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
        </xe:djAccordionPane>
    </xe:djAccordionContainer>
    <xp:panel styleClass="rowMargin"></xp:panel>
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:image url="/slika4.jpg" id="image1"></xp:image></xp:panel></xp:view>
```

Comment: is this an error you get in designer or in a browser? also is there a stack trace? and finally did you try to clean the application?

Comment: I updated the post. I get this in the designer.

Answer (score 5):

I have gotten this from time to time when upgrading various servers, and libraries etc.

Generally i remove the application from the list of applications, close designer, re open, open the app again and clean it. This has always worked from me

Comment: I've done this maybe 20 times... Still the same thing happens.

Comment: sounds very strange, never had it hang around after that, and I have to update regularly. Couple of things to try: open the package explorer view and see can you see / open the file (even with a text editor). If you have access to the source (either through package explorer or by creating ondisk project or old copy) try create a new XPage with same content to see is it something in the source causing an error

Comment: I've found out that it happens only on few Xpages and I know exactly which ones. Others are opened just fine. But how do I resolve them?
Thank you for the help though :)

Comment: yes this is what happened to me also, but again my answer above fixed it. Could be something that longer exists / java files been updated etc. thats why cleaning will generally fix this as it regenerates the java files

Comment: select the application, click project in the top menu bar and select clean

Comment: Sry maybe I should have referred to it as a project clean. Ok you can check if this is working correctly by opening the project explorer, open the app, open local and delete the contents of the xsp folder. click clean and these should re generate. I would close all open XPages before doing this and after this remove app close designer etc. again. If this doesn't work maybe the openNTF install didn't happen correctly. I'd completely uninstall / reinstall those plugins. restart server and try again. Long way to go i no

Comment: I did what you told me. Deleted the generated java files, cleaned, removed, opened again, still the same.
Before I even posted this question I removed the plugins and installed them again 3 times (just to make sure).
I'm hitting against the wall here...
Thank you for your help though

Comment: Do you have any way of getting the contents of the file to see if recreating it will fix it? try right clicking on the project in the package explorer view, click export, general, file system and ok. If this works you should hopefully get all the files and be able to open the damaged files in a text editor and from there create a new XPage and copy the contents

Comment: can you open the XPage in a text editor (notepad, notepad++ etc.) without an error? If this will work perhaps you can copy the contents of the XPage and go back to your app and create a new blank XPage and paste the contents from the file in. If this still causes the error its something in your code, if it doesn't i'm not sure what the error was but theres a workaround

Comment: I did this, and still get the error... So yea, it's the code. But I have no idea what's with the code that makes it bad.
This is the code from the Xpage http://pastebin.com/nQ3Ln6kL

Comment: I can't test most of this as i don't have those custom controls so its complaining because of that. One thing that popped into my head is there are a lot of non English characters in this file, this isn't some kind of encoding issue is it? have you had to change any settings previously for this to work in your last version? failing that the only option I can see is comment out sections to see where is failing. your calling a lot of custom controls here so maybe its an error in one of those thats being used in a few XPages

Comment: that's what i was afraid of... Well, thank you for trying! I'll make sure to post the results tomorrow...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help anymore. Yes if you find the issue and don't understand post it and link to it here and I'll try help you with that

Answer (score 1):

You can clean the project in the Domino Designer by opening your database and select "Project" and "Clean..." - select the "project" (i.e. your database) and hit [Ok]